# match if statement excel

Tags: if-statement, excel-2010

I am trying to match termed employees in column c with against a master list of all firm emoployees in column e with the following:

```
=IF(MATCH(C2,$E$2:$E$13691,0),"N", "Y")
```

The formula returns N correctly but instead of a Y I get the #N/A ref error. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For `=match()` to work, the value of the cells you are referencing have to be exact. Also, the match function only provides the location of the queried term in the search array. So, if you do this right, it will return a value greater than 0, which we can use to our advantage. Your `=if()` function requires a logical test to work; if `match` returns a number, it means it has found a match in the master list. We can test that number in `if` and see if it is greater than 0 (which it will be); you should get `"y"`.

Try this: `=if(match(c2,$e:$e,0)>0,"y","n")`

Also, another problem could lie in different entries from cols `C` to `E`. Are you using names? If yes, this is a bad practice; there are too many variables you can mess up when entering text strings. Try using ID numbers instead of names. You can then use `=VLOOKUP()` to directly reference and match your employee names to employee ID numbers. This will work in a Workbook across different sheets.

You *could* try to do string matching. But, I recommend you switch to ID numbers.

Comment: I am using an account number and the formula works I just don't understand why I am not getting a "Y" return. Functionally the match works fine but I'd like to make it look a little cleaner without the N/As

Comment: @Alex just updated the ans. I noticed something wrong with your if.

Comment: Still not working, could I use the isnumber function somehow instead?

Comment: nevermind figured it out, this did it:                            =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(c2,$E$2:$E$13691,0)),"N", "Y")  just needed an extra ). Thanks!

Comment: @alex Yeah that's exactly what I was going to give you. Slightly round-about method but reliable. Make sure you answer your own question and accept it as answered!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also try:

```vb
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,$E$2:$E$13691,0)),"N", "Y")
```

A non-match will take you to the else case.